# Angular 2 Use sevice with mandatory parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular. I use **service** to share logic with **2 components**. my service should **call some function**. function needs parameters that **I haven't in service**. what should I do?

**service.ts:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class BookinActionService{
 bookingActionTypesClick(status) {
    switch (status) {
      case "AllowedArchive":
       this.requestService.acceptTicket(Number(bookingId));
      case "AllowedSeeDetail":
        this.router.navigate(['request-detail', request.bookingId]);
    }
  }

}
```

I haven't **request.bookingId** in service so how to do that?

Comment: I think you should consider the service non-stateful that gets any requirement via argument. in your case defining `bookingId` as an argument.